# CSS transition property on page exit

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, transition

I need a few objects on my pages to animate out when a user clicks a link. I want each object to scale and fade out but not all objects such as the navigation buttons.

I was thinking that upon a user clicking a link, the page delays 1 second before opening the redirecting the link to allow fade out giving the animation time to take effect.

Comment: could you show your attempts in a fiddle?

Comment: Take a look at below web site on Using CSS transitions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the JS event `window.onbeforeunload`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload

It will hopefully be enough to just run the exit animations when this function is triggered - it generally takes the browser around a second to unload the page completely but this varies depending on your browser, page size and cpu speed.

Assuming you're using plain JS and you know how to do CSS transitions, the simple way to make animations occur on page exit is something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    document.getElementById('myDiv').className = 'out';
}
```

Where `myDiv` id the element you want to animate and `out` is the CSS class representing the final stage of your transition.

**Here is a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X5vKS/**

If you need finer control over the wait time, you could use the `onbeforeunload` function with `setTimeout` to delay the page exit by the length of time of your animation. This is slightly complex for a JS beginner but is quite doable.

Comment: i have no idea how to implement this lol. I am a novice. can you assist? much appreciated..

Comment: You didnt provide much info in the question (always include code if possible) but I've added an example to show you the principal.

Comment: I've added a working JSfiddle example above. Please click the tick mark next to my answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for that but when I put that exact code into my html editor is does not go red. It will go red once I click the link, then press the back button in my browser... I will press tick because you have put time into this but still not working

Comment: Thanks. My fiddle above works fine in the latest versions of Chrome/Firefox/IE. If you need help debugging your project, you could post your code to a new fiddle and ask a new question on stack overflow