# CSS transition on page exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-transitions, transition

Hi Why does this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5vKS/

only work with some links ?.
Its from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873574/css-transition-property-on-page-exit#new-answer?newreg=1851445a1571419481ffcff4511b71c9)

which I am not allowed to comment on till have 50 rep.

If I add `index.html` it goes straight to link with no transition if I add full address to page `www.mywebsite.info/index` it goes straight to link and does not do the transition .

But if I add `google.com`, `yahoo.com` etc it works fine.

I am using a `.info` domain if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `http://` in `href` before the site.

As you have not given much detail, I think the problem is that your page is loading too quickly in order for you to see the transition. I suggest you add a timeout in onbeforeunload function.

This adds a 2 seconds timeout.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
    }, 2000);
}
```

If you want to wait after the function, then do this -

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

    document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myLink').className = '';
    }, 2000);
}
```

Now, onbeforeunload doesn't provide a whole lot of functionalities for security reasons, but above should do for you.

For more information on timing events in javascript, read this - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: I have already tryed that this is not to do with syntax of the url .
http://www.google.com  works
http://www,mysite.info  does not work

Comment: Yes it is a very fast loading page I guess that is the correct answer how would I go about adding a timeout to this code ?. I am a complete noob when comes to js.
And thanks for your replies.

Comment: I have 2 bugs with that code 1st if using `www.google.com` the delay works but now the transition does not work .
But if I use my `www.mysite.info` niether the delay or the transition work ? .

Comment: Then you will have to post your code in jsfiddle. I tried and it was working well.

Comment: by jsfiddle do you mean this 

`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>` 
as I said im a complete noob here Im ok at html and css thou

Comment: Sorry you confused me I have already shown the code in jsfiddle link at top of page i am using like that only changing the url.

Comment: I re-checked and the transition and delay both are working fine for me.

Comment: Is that a valid page that you are using?

Comment: Im lost because the transition is definatly not working for me with your code but works fine with the other code using google as link .I just tested in chrome firefox and ei this is my code :

Comment: `<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js?ver=3.3.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';
    }, 2000);
}
</script> 
<a href='https://www.google.com' id='myLink'>click me and watch me go red before the page unloads</a>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Ok, can you try one more thing - put script tag AFTER after the link html and just before </body> tag and see if that works.

Comment: Hi I will try this when I am back home later .I will add I am running this in browsers using the preview feature in dreamweaver just incase that has any effect on outcome ?.

Thank you for your help so far trying to solve this.

Comment: Hi I tried this and it did not work. I also setup easyphp server and tried in that also it did not work. But with the old code it did work the 1st time with my url .I guess after that its too fast because of cache so the original problem was definatly because my page was loading to fast.So now I just need to get this timeout and transition working together.

Comment: Well this is how the timeout is added in javascript. Make sure your site is up and running, try and debug through console, hope you find the issue.

Comment: Yes I think it it working just not how I want.The timeout function is stopping the transition till timeout is over.What I want is the transition to start 1st and then timeout leaving the page.

Comment: Hi I see how the update is supposed to work and with it the transition is fireing but sadly the timeout is still not working so if it is a fast loading page you still dont see transition.I will follow the link you gave and try learn something from there thank you.

Comment: I removed `document.getElementById('myLink').className = 'out';`
from your code just to see if the timeout would work on its on and no it doesn't work it just goes straight to url. So there is definatly a problem with the timeout function.I am wondering whether the timeout function simply cant work within the onbeforeunload function ?.